# What ports are used when running asp.net core 5 api from command line?

Tags: .net, .net-core

I'm trying to understand what ports are used by a normal asp.net core api project.

I build the project and navigate to the `bin\Release\net5.0` folder.

I run the api from the command line with `dotnet api.dll`.

The process starts and gives this output:

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Production
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: C:\mypath\api\bin\Release\net5.0
```

What port is my api listening on now?

When I run with IIS Express I can navigate to `https://localhost:44322/swagger/index.html` as the 44322 port is specified in the launchSettings.json file.

But when I run from the command line I can't reach anything. I've tried all of these urls without success:

```
https://localhost:44322/swagger/index.html
https://localhost:5000/swagger/index.html
https://localhost:5001/swagger/index.html
```

I'm probably missing some fundamental understanding of how this is put together so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't have a specific answer, but `netstat -ano | find "LISTENING"` by a command-prompt will tell you what local adapters and ports are being listened on.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Good tip. Tried it and diffed the listings before and after starting the program. It's ports 5000 and 5001 that shows up. But I can't access the https://localhost:5000/swagger/index.html or 5001 endpoints for some reason. So... still a mystery how this actually works.

Comment: Facing the same issue, did you get an answer?

Answer (score 0):

In my case on default settings swagger runs at `http://localhost:5000/index.html` and
`https://localhost:5001/index.html`